# can i update a column with subquery returned more than 1 value

Tags: sql-server-2012

[![tow search result from ONE Table with different DOCID][1]][1]

[1]: http://i.stack**strong text**.imgur.com/vLPwr.jpg

I want to update in the same table with record that i get from another docid

i try that

```
Declare
@DOCID nvarchar(100),
@SBJCODE NUMERIC(3,0),
@SUBJECT_ORDER NUMERIC(9,0),
@IS_ACTIVE NUMERIC(9,0)
select @SBJCODE = sbjcode from ASSIGNMENT_SUBJECTS where DOCID =    '274FC727-4C5A-467F-A2CC-14CC14275E0A'  
select @IS_ACTIVE = IS_ACTIVE from ASSIGNMENT_SUBJECTS where DOCID='274FC727-4C5A-467F-A2CC-14CC14275E0A'
select @SUBJECT_ORDER = SUBJECT_ORDER from ASSIGNMENT_SUBJECTS where DOCID = '274FC727-4C5A-467F-A2CC-14CC14275E0A'
UPDATE ASSIGNMENT_SUBJECTS SET SUBJECT_ORDER = @SUBJECT_ORDER, IS_ACTIVE = @IS_ACTIVE 
WHERE DOCID  = 'ACC4A511-4692-49DA-9FC9-F68090862EAC' AND SBJCODE = @SBJCODE
```

and result was

(0 row(s) affected) :/

can any body help me

Comment: does select top 10 * from ASSIGNMENT_SUBJECTS where DOCID =    '274FC727-4C5A-467F-A2CC-14CC14275E0A' return somithing? What is the output of select @SBJCODE

Comment: the select statement return 10 row and the output of  select @SBJCODE 
return (112)

Comment: you are not using the same docid between the 1st 3 queries and the update. Perhaps DOCID  = 'ACC4A511-4692-49DA-9FC9-F68090862EAC' does not exist when SBJCODE = 12

Comment: I have a table (assignment_subjects)
I want to update in the same table but i don't know how :/
i want say 

    update assignment_subjects set IS_ACTIVE 
    where (docid) = 'C07CD832-DB18-4AEA-B9A7-00FFB264B485'
    = (IS_ACTIVE) where (docid) = '1535AA0F-64FC-416A-8B1A-00054B915ED5'
    and (SBJCODE) where (docid) = 'C07CD832-DB18-4AEA-B9A7-00FFB264B485'
    = (SBJCODE) where (docid) = '1535AA0F-64FC-416A-8B1A-00054B915ED5'